# Device access through Rails on LAN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip, lan, plc

The device I am attempting to access is a PLC with a built in web server. I am trying to pull data through the PLC's unique IP address. I have a computer running the Rails application sitting inside the same Local Area Network as the PLC. With the computer still INSIDE the network, can I access a device IP through my Rails app? I'm not sure how the request works. Will Rails move directly to the ISP and search that way or will it scan the local network first?

Comment: Whether using the PLC's IP works is an IP matter (as in "internet protocol", at the internet layer level. Other than that it's still going to be HTTP requests to the PLC's address. What's your question exactly?

Comment: My question is this...I can access the device in development mode inside the network. How can I access this same device in production mode outside the network. The PLC is accessed through a local IP...but this IP is only recognized inside the network. I know I need some sort of proxy that allows my app to talk to the device. It is a MODBUS device if that is of any help. Do I spin a server inside the network to handle requests from the app in production?

Comment: I am not familiar with Modbus but from the outside you might be able to contact it with some port forwarding